# Selecting a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to search for a substring inside the href's in the below code and select the link AFTER the selected string. So, for example the string "page=2" would access the third link.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="container">
<a href='test.php?page=1&title=a title'><a title</a>
<a href='test.php?page=2&title=another title'><another title</a>
<a href='test.php?page=3&title=a last title'><a last title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery("a[href*='page=2']").next("a");` try this

Comment: I tried it like this to check if it selected correctly -

alert(jQuery("a[href*=page2]").next("a").href("href")); 

But nothing happens.

Comment: alert(jQuery("a[href*='page=2']").next("a").attr("href")); use attr instead of href

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$("a[href*='page2']").next("a");
```

Or simply:

```
$("a[href*='page2']").next();
```